# Why is KVO not working for my key?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a queue variable:

```
var notificationQueue = Queue<[NotificationAttribute: AnyObject?]>()
```

where `NotificationAttribute` is `enum NotificationAttribute : String {..}`

My `Queue` class is

```
class Queue<T> : NSObject {...}
```

I'm using this with KVO:

```
self.willChangeValueForKey("notificationQueue")
notificationQueue.enqueue([
    .Title : attributes[.Title],
    ])
self.didChangeValueForKey("notificationQueue")
```

This worked perfectly before I updated to Swift 2. Now it produces the error:

```
'[<NotificationSingleton 0x137604dd0>  valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key notificationQueue.'
```

I thought that because Queue was a subclass of NSObject, then it would be KVO compliant? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: notificationQueue looks like a local variable rather than a class member variable.

Comment: @MartinH It's declared like that in the class' scope.